# Distorted and weak sound on some backing tracks

Tags: mixers

When I plug my stereo backing tracks into dual mono or stereo inputs on my desk, some of them sound very tinny and quiet until I unplug one side. Any ideas? Thanks. Mick

Comment: this is called phase cancellation, check your input settings (look for a button with a symbol that looks like  "0" combined with a "/" . And check with another pair of cables..

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are facing might be caused by a phase inversion between your two stereo channels.

This phase inversion might occur at various points in the chain :

- The recorded backing track might have a phase inversion
- The cable used to connect the player to the desk input
- A phase inversion switch activated on one channel in the desk